# Play Org-Pomodoro sounds

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, microsoft-windows

I am running Emacs version 25.0.92.1, Spacemacs 0.105.x, Windows 7. In my `.spacemacs`, in `dotspacemacs/user-config` I have:

```
;; Org
;; Org-pomodoro
(setq org-pomodoro-length 25)
(setq org-pomodoro-short-break-length 5)
(setq org-pomodoro-long-break-length 15)
(setq org-pomodoro-play-sounds 1)
```

In `.emacs.d\elpa\org-pomodoro-20151217.553\resources` I have `bell.wav`, `bell_multiple.wav` and `tick.wav`. When running a pomodoro it doesn't play any sounds. What do I need to change to get sounds working and what do I need to change to use my own sounds?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Spacemacs. Spacemacs is only a config. By adding Spacemacs to the question and tag, you are limiting the number of people who would even read the question. As a Spacemacs user, if you know where to put the config stuff, this question boils down to a more general question of why this is not working and what needs to be done to fix it. "Where" to put the fix could be different for each user.

Comment: You have to have active pomodoro in order to customize it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like org-pomodoro potentially uses `sound-wav` to play sounds.

Install it, along with `powershell`:

```
M-x package-install [RET] sound-wav [RET]
M-x package-install [RET] poweshell [RET]
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can it be play over ssh connection?

Answer (score 1):

Run `M-x customize-group` and you should see a group called `org-pomodoro`. All related options, including the sound, should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `customize-group` does not have `org-pomodoro` in it, though I am able to run a pomodoro.

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Spacemacs' org layer is missing the `sound-wav` package.  I just had to add it to my `.spacemacs`' additional packages and restart Emacs:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(sound-wav)
```

To hear the ticking sound, enable *Org Pomodoro Ticking Sound P* in `customize-group [RET] org-pomodoro [RET]`.

For vanilla Emacs, you might have to install `sound-wav` (and `powershell` if you're in Winbugs):

```
M-x package-install [RET] sound-wav [RET]
M-x package-install [RET] powershell [RET]
```

And add to your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'sound-wav)
```

You can test `sound-wav` with

```
(sound-wav-play "/path/to/audio.wav")
```