# Pomidor mute to play sounds

Tags: org-mode

I am running Emacs 26.1 on MacOs Mojave and have problem to play sounds with 
[pomidor:](https://github.com/TatriX/pomidor)

pomidor is installed in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/pomidor-20180614.828`

Reference to the source code `pomidor.el`, it warn that 
(warn "This Emacs binary lacks sound support")))

```
 120 (defun pomidor-play-sound-file-emacs (file)                                                                                                                     
 121   "Play FILE by starting new Emacs process."                                                                                                                    
 122   (if (fboundp 'play-sound-internal)                                                                                                                            
 123       (start-process "pomidor-play-sound-file-emacs"                                                                                                            
 124                      nil                                                                                                                                        
 125                      (car command-line-args)                                                                                                                    
 126                      "-Q"                                                                                                                                       
 127                      "--batch"                                                                                                                                  
 128                      "--eval" (format "(play-sound-file \"%s\")" file))                                                                                         
 129     (warn "This Emacs binary lacks sound support")))
```

Since it fails to play sounds, I config the ~/.emacs.d/init.el following the instruction [TatriX/pomidor: Pomidor is a simple and cool pomodoro technique timer.](https://github.com/TatriX/pomidor)

1, To disable or configure sounds:

```
(setq pomidor-sound-tick nil
      pomidor-sound-tack nil
      pomidor-sound-overwork (expand-file-name (concat pomidor-dir "overwork.wav"))
      pomidor-sound-break-over (expand-file-name (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Music/overwork.wav")))
```

and place the sounds to Musics directory

```
$ ls ~/Music
iTunes  overwork.wav  tack.wav  tick.wav
```

When restart emacs it prompts:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: pomidor-dir
pomidor.el reside in:
$ pwd ; tree 
/Users/gaowei/.emacs.d/elpa/pomidor-20180614.828
.
├── overwork.wav
├── pomidor-autoloads.el
├── pomidor-pkg.el
├── pomidor.el
├── pomidor.elc
├── tack.wav
└── tick.wav
```

2, Provide customized function to play sounds

> if your Emacs can't play sounds you can provide your own function to do it:

```
(setq pomidor-play-sound-file
      (lambda (file)
        (start-process "my-pomidor-play-sound"
                       nil
                       "mplayer"
                       file)))
```

I wait 2 hours to run 3 pomodoros, but it stayed mute.

I checked the problem and find there is not such a function called `"my-pomidor-play-sound"` in pomidor.el.

```
$ grep -n 'my-pomidor' pomidor.el
#return nothing
$ grep -n 'pomidor-play' pomidor.el
120:(defun pomidor-play-sound-file-emacs (file)
123:      (start-process "pomidor-play-sound-file-emacs"
131:(defcustom pomidor-play-sound-file #'pomidor-play-sound-file-emacs ;;
329:  "Play FILE using `pomidor-play-sound-file' function if any."
330:  (when (and file (functionp pomidor-play-sound-file))
331:    (funcall pomidor-play-sound-file file)))
```

It comes to conclusion that I should write a defun `my-pomidor-play-sound` then could start-process

Alternatively, I found a solution [org mode - Play Org-Pomodoro sounds - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24246/play-org-pomodoro-sounds)

Which simple introduce `M-x package install sound-wav`.

Unfortunately, the pomidor keeps mute.

How could I get it playing sounds?